# jQuery hide html column with button click using link_to on rails and HAML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to hide an html column with a click of a button with jQuery hide method.

Here's my html:

```
  %br.clear
  - @cards.each do |card|
  %div{class: "hide_#{card.id}"} <- added this to solve issue
    .existing-credit-card-details.nine.columns.omega.alpha{id: dom_id(card)} <- this is my target
      .cc-select.one.column.alpha.omega
        Random text here
      .cc-type.three.columns.alpha.omega{class: card.card_type.downcase}
        %span.mobile-heading.em Card Type
        .icon
        %span.type= card.card_type
      .cc-number.two.columns.alpha.omega
        %span.mobile-heading.em Number
        ****
        Random text here
      .cc-expiration.two.columns.alpha.omega
        %span.mobile-heading.em Expiration Date
        Random card expiration dates
      .cc-expiration.two.columns.alpha.omega
        %span.mobile-heading.em
        = link_to (image_tag("icons/delete.png")),
            spree.credit_card_url(card),
            :remote => true, :method => :delete,
            :id => 'delete_card'
    %br.clear
```

![This is how it looks][1]

The link_to button is equal to: `<a href="http://localhost:9393/credit_cards/12211" id="delete_card" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Delete" src="/assets/icons/delete.png"></a>`

I tried with the following Javascript:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#delete_card").click(function(){
          $(".existing-credit-card-details nine columns omega alpha" id="<%= dom_id(card) %>").hide(1000);
        });
      });
```

So when I click on #delete_card .existing-credit-card-details.nine.columns.omega.alpha{id: dom_id(card)} should be hidden.

I've tried to figure it out by looking at other questions and browsing online, but my JS skills are lacking.

**Solution:**

Added:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".delete_card").on("click", function(){
          $(this).parents(".hide_#{card.id}").hide("fast");
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think you can do the following:

```
$("#delete_card").click(function(){ 
     $(".existing-credit-card-details nine columns omega alpha").find('id', 'the id you are looking for').hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did't work, posted solution, thank you both for your help.